# Combining of two or more ultra low voltage DC/DC step up converter chip's (LTC3108) output

Tags: energy, energy-harvesting

I want to use one LTC3108 with micro solar panel and other LTC3108 with TEG panel. Can I connect two LTC3108s' output to the one battery charger chip's input (max1555 for example)?

Comment: I expect you can but there isn't enough detail in your question as to what might happen or what you want to happen.

Comment: In general, connecting outputs (of regulators/converters) is a bad idea as unexpected currents can flow. If somehow this is taken care of then it might be possible. Using (Schottky) diodes it should be possible to implement this safely but you will get a voltage drop due to the diodes.

Comment: @Andyaka Two LTC3108  will be work always producing 5V output both. So there are two different voltage source in same voltage level.  And li-po charger chip works with 5V input and normally can charge the single cell battery with one LTC3108 connected to the solar panel or TEG element.

Comment: The LTC3108 datasheet doesn't explicitly say you can put them in parallel, so I wouldn't do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is unclear what behavior you are hoping for.  Do you want both LTC3108 circuits to be connected to the chargers input so either can be used, but still only one of the two at any given time? This is called 'Oring'.  The simplest (and lowest performance) way or oring parallel voltage sources is using oring diodes, which are usually just a schottky diode on the positive rail of each power supply.  In other words, you'd put a schottky in series with each of the LTC3108's outputs.

This comes at no small cost, however.  You lose ~600mV and likely several milliwatts (the dearest commodity in any energy harvesting situation) due to those diodes, and also have to step up the voltage even more to compensate, which increases losses other places.  And the problem with oring is that it is OR-ing.  The load is powered by one thing, or the other thing.  Not both things at once.  In the case of the diodes, which ever LTC3108 can muster more voltage than the other will be the chosen one and power the circuit essentially by its lonesome, until or if the other LTC3108 becomes more wattful. Or, uh, powerful is the correct word I guess.

If you want **load sharing**, which is where both LTC3108s share the work, ideally in a proportional way depending on the power available from each one, both powering the load simultaneously, you can do that too, but you'll need some help.

Linear makes a very wide variety of "ideal diode" ICs for just about any possible application of synchronous rectifiers.  Ideal diodes are, of course, marketing speak for a mosfet and synchronous rectification controller.  It's a way to fake a diode by just turning a mosfet on and off in the same conditions a a diode would be conducting or not, yielding a pretty good approximation of a diode but with purely ohmic losses rather than normal diode loss junction loss.

For load sharing, I would recommend connecting the LTC3108s to an [LTC4413](http://www.linear.com/product/LTC4413) load sharing chip.  It's relatively inexpensive (a fair bit cheaper than just one LTC3108) and couldn't be simpler or easier to use.  It will act as an ORing controller when the two power inputs get to far apart in voltages, but if they are supplying similar voltage levels, the LTC4413 will actively share the load by dynamically adjusting the the voltage drop across each MOSFET to share current proportional to whatever load current each input can provide with equalized output voltages.  Basically, it just works and you don't have to worry about anything.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can not connect outputs of LTC3108 in parallel "as is".

However, you can use two Schottky diodes (as suggested by @FakeMoustache) to connect them safely in parallel. You can find silicon diodes with forward voltage drop below 0.3 V for your task, so power loss is below 6% that is acceptable.

USING TWO SOURCES IN PARALLEL

OK, I got your idea about parallel using of two sources. Look where it leads us.

We can hardly connect two power sources in series. Each one has individual loading performance, and it depends on conditions (light intensity / temperature difference). For example: your system gets a good light, however, the temperature difference is zero. So, the useful current from solar panel passes through TEG and just dissipates energy there (helps conduct some heat). Your device gets significantly less power.

Same considerations apply to the opposite case, when there is no light.

Therefore, each power source has to be converted individually.

Do not expect too much from LTC3108. It is a simple IC that has little internal intelligence. It has rather low efficiency (below 40% or 50%, depending on conditions). So, if you really need to collect all energy you can get, LTC3108 is not a good choice.

The optimal solution has to be based on two discreet converters with the common control circuit. It is a complex engineering task.

May be, it is better to give up one of two sources and to use a simple solution? It can be based on the last sample design in LTC3108 datasheet.

Comment: by this way will sources really be combined or highest voltage source will be selected as source?

Comment: Oh, I got you need to select ONE of two power sources? The Schottky diodes designe takes power from higher voltage source. Summing power from two independent sources is far more complex task.

Comment: Yes im planning to combine different sources

Comment: In my system both TEG and solar panel will be feeded to give their power output full always.

Comment: I don't agree on the fact that putting them in series will give *significantly* less power. Given the low currents that those sources will provide anyway, doubling the ESR of one source is not dramatic, and is certainly more efficient than schottky diodes, which would completely disable one source (not even counting for the voltage drop). But the sources must sure be consistent in their characteristics.

Comment: So what to do ?

Comment: Combining solar cells and TEGs before booster IC is possible?

Comment: The LTC3108 is a fantastic part and certainly one of the best energy harvesting solutions out there.  It's an analog control chip, statements like 'possessing little internal intelligence' is a meaningless statement in that context.  And it is NOT simple.  If it was, then there would be dozens of energy harvesting chips capable of bootstrapping itself from 20mV.  Instead, there is exactly one, and the LTC3108 is it.  Do you not understand how amazing that is?  Sure, it doesn't have a million transistors.  But the fab processes and physics needed for it to exist at all are not 'simple'.

Comment: Also, your statement of low efficiency is completely false.  It is low if you make a totally invalid comparison like you have.  I'm sure a semi truck has relatively poor gas mileage compared to a motorcycle.  And? That's not a useful comparison, and ignores the criteria that actually matters: one can haul freight, the other can haul a person, possibly 2.  The LTC3108 is a great choice because it CAN collect all the energy you can get.  Chips that are more efficient also won't work in energy harvesting conditions, so the energy "you can get" is none at all.  50% is high for energy harvesting.

Comment: Finally, you can call something a poor choice if you have a specific and superior choice to suggest. Where is yours? What chip should he use instead? Surely you have a 'good choice' with which you are comparing with, permitting you to call it a 'poor choice. Or did you seriously tell someone they made a poor choice even though you had nothing to compare it to? If it's a poor choice, then by all means, link us to the better option.  Link us to that more efficient chip that can run of a few dozen mV from a TEG. If you can't, then don't call it a poor choice, as you have no right to call it that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what characteristics the solar panel and the TEG panel have, but if you can put them both in series and then use this "block" as the input of a single LTC3108, their two power would sum up. As a bonus, the whole thing would be cheaper. However I can't guarantee it makes sense in your specific case.

Another idea, maybe, is to use an arrangement like the one shown at the very last page of the datasheet (Dual TEG Energy Harvester). They seem to chain two LTC3108 through the AUX pin, although it's hard to guess what it does exactly, then. Whether this sums power or just selects one source (based one what ?) is not clear.

Comment: which charastics need to be considered?

Comment: I need summing circuit for different 5V voltage sources in order to charge a battery via charger IC.

Comment: @dim, I checked LTC3108. They just use internal diodes to use one of two energy sources. So this "chaining" does not help.

Comment: To put both sources in series, you must check that the ESR of both are in the same range. Their allowable current should be in the same range also (but I guess it's very small so this should be OK), and the voltage they provide when put in series and with the appropriate sun exposure / temperature difference are in the same range also.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, by tying their VAUX pins together and then just using the VOUT pin from either chip.

Comment: This only works for selecting one or the other.  He may be hoping for load sharing, and the LTC3108 cannot do load sharing unaided.